# How to convert string to instance name in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a symbol in the library,and in the stage I have twelve objects of the symbolic.
Each symbol have a instance name, from a-l

In addition I have  twelve objects **(image )** with instance name, from 1-12

I clicked on one of the objects of the image I can extract the name object **(a-l)** from the array but not access while.

How can I convert string to instance name in as3

```
    var abc:Array = ["0","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l"];


    function item_onMouseUp(event:MouseEvent):void
    {

        var clip:Sprite = Sprite(event.currentTarget);
        var c:int = int(clip.name);
        trace("abc[c]=" +[abc[c]]);

 //The problem here
        if (clip.hitTestObject([abc[c]]))
        {
                trace("===");
            }

        clip.stopDrag();
    }
```

To example in the trace win I get

```
abc[c]=d
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "d" to flash.display.DisplayObject.
    at gamewitoutserver_fla::MainTimeline/item_onMouseUp()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (clip.hitTestObject(this[abc[c]]))
    {
            trace("===");
    }
```

To address an object property (that is your named display object you add at design time with an instance name) via a string, use `this[string]`.